# Accessing POJO properties from neo4j bolt response

Tags: java, neo4j

I have set up a simple example of using the neo4j bolt java driver to execute a query. The code looks like this:

```
Session session = driver.session();
String q = makeQuery();
StatementResult result = session.run(q);
while ( result.hasNext() )
{
    Record record = result.next();
    List<Object> delivDates = record.get( "delivDates" ).asList();
    for (Object delivDate : delivDates) {
        System.out.println( delivDate );
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
{dateStr=2016-11-05, day=5, cutoff=1.47719058917E12}
{dateStr=2016-11-10, day=10, cutoff=1.477190386013E12}
...
```

I would like to be able to access the `dateStr` property on the delivDate object. I thought I should be able to something like `delivDate.get("dateStr")` but method `get` cannot be resolved. How do I do this?

The result set from the query looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention the query you are executing and the node properties, i am giving a very minimum example to retrieve node attributes in Neo4j.

```
Session session = driver.session();
session.run( "CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})" );

StatementResult result = session.run( "MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title" );
while (result.hasNext()){
    Record record = result.next();
    System.out.println( record.get("title").asString() + " " + record.get("name").asString() );
}

session.close();
driver.close();
```

More comprehensive example can be found [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/blob/1.1/examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/docs/driver/Examples.java).